# Why is my static IP address not set to what I made it in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 file?

Tags: centos, rhel, ip, nmcli, static-linking

I have made the following changes to /network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 file in order to try and get a static IP address (added ip i want ending in .49, added gateway, Prefix and Subnet mask (  [image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW3sd.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qamcp.png image of file included)

But i get this error message when I attempt to restart network
(image of error included)
[image]
When I check Jornalctl -xe I get this
(image included)[image]

*Possible solution i found: “If you are using NetworkManager there will be more items that you would need to configure like: GATEWAY, DOMAIN, DNS1, DNS2, etc.  If you are not using NetworkManager, you will need to configure the gateway address in the /etc/sysconfig/network file, and the DNS resolvers (if required) in the /etc/resolv.conf file I added DNS="8/8/8/8".” **But I do not know how to configure DNS, Domain etc.***

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please don't post commands or test output as images. Paste them directly to the question / answer, enclosed in the code brackets `{ }`. For things like entire logs the best way is to upload them to Pastebin and just drop a link here. In general in a question like this you should include details like your exact OS version, relevant configs, commands you use etc. I'd recommend checking the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how these sites work.

Comment: please remove the pictures of text ... add the text

Answer (score 0):

Don't represent as subnetmask in configuration file it is wrong, instead represent as

**NETMASK=255.255.255.0**

then, restart the network

systemctl restart network